# VBA code will not give accurate ListBox multi select query results

Tags: ms-access, vba

I gave a giant linked Excel table in Access with a bunch of old historic data.
I have created a multiselect ListBox in a form that allows the user to select multiple "quarters of the year" to display that data of the selected quarter from the historic data.

My issue is the VBA code that I have written is not filtering out the results correctly. For example, I will select Quarter 1 and Quarter 2 from the listbox, run the query button, and it will still give me unfiltered results, it just shows all the data for Quarter 1, 2, 3, and 4. It is displaying all the correct information, it just will not filter the criteria that is specified from the list box.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()

DoCmd.RunSQL ("Delete * from quarters")

For x = 0 To Me.List0.ListCount - 1
    If Me.List0.Selected(x) > 0 Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL ("Insert into quarters values ('" & _
            Me.List0.ItemData(x) & "')")
    End If
Next

DoCmd.OpenQuery "Quarter"

End Sub
```

I would just like to know how to get it to filter the correct results. Thanks.

Comment: I'd put a breakpoint and single step ...

Comment: Hey peakpeak, thanks for your response! Could you possibly give me an example or direct to where I could find an example of a breakpoint and single step?

Comment: That is basic VBA troubleshooting knowledge. You are required to know it if you code in VBA: Breakpoint F9, Run F5, Single Step F8 etc ...

Comment: Sorry, I learned all this terminology a different way, thank you for your input.

Comment: In the VB Editor, click on the white vertical bar to the left of the code, just opposite the DoCmd line. You should see a brown circle appear. Now when you run the code it will pause when it hits that line. You can then step through your code one line at a time by pressing F8 repeatedly. That will give you some idea as to what's happening

Comment: I am still not sure how to do this as my code is not able to show step by step how it is working because it is being done on a form.

Comment: It's VBA code; any line that's not a variable declaration can have a breakpoint.  It being on a form is right where it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code contains a logic error here ...

```vba
If Me.List0.Selected(x) > 0 Then
    DoCmd.RunSQL "Insert ..."
End If
```

The problem is that when `x` is the row index for one of the listbox selected items, `Me.List0.Selected(x)` returns True, which is -1.  And since -1 is not greater than zero, the `If ... Then` condition evaluates as False, so no row is inserted.

Examine that "quarters" table.  It should be empty because you deleted all its rows at the start of the procedure, and added no rows after.

Change that line to this ...

```vba
If Me.List0.Selected(x) = True Then
```

Then run the code again.  If the "Quarter" query still does not open filtered as you expect, please add the query's SQL to your question and describe how the query result differs from what you want.